# R Studio: Selecting and Counting multiple Columns at once

Tags: r, count

I've recently started to learn Data Analysis with R and R Studio and have a small problem.
My data set looks like this:

[image]

(It's basically a "Have you visited City XYZ? - Yes/No" Questionnaire)

I would like to create an overview of which City was visited the most.
Therefore I would probably need to count columns 4 to 23 which are >0, right?

However, I couldn't find a proper way to write that statement in R.
Could someone give me a hint?

I would appreciate it.
Stay healthy everyone!

Comment: `colSums(your_data[4:23])`

Comment: Wow. Thank you very much!